# R: How can I store various random numbers generated by a loop in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, random, storage, sampling

I want to generate 10 times 20 random numbers between 1 and 100. The final matrix therefore should include 200 numbers in total.
This my way, how I tried to solve it:

```
x <- 10
N <- 20
A <- matrix()

for (i in 1:x) {
  
  A[i] <- sample(1:100, N, FALSE)
  
}

A
```

It results, that something seems to be wrong with A.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma while indexing. I'm right that each row of the same matrix should be filled with random numbers?

```r
x <- 10
N <- 20
A <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = x, ncol = N)

for (i in 1:x) {
  
  A[i,] <- sample(1:100, N, TRUE)
  
}

A
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
#>  [1,]   13   20   13   20   13   18   17    2   18     8     5    17    18
#>  [2,]    1    7   18   15    3   20    4    4   13    10     7     6    15
#>  [3,]    7    3    1   16   12   19   16   16   16    17    15    14    19
#>  [4,]   15   19    4    6    4    5    4    5    8    12    20    14    17
#>  [5,]   14    4    9    7   18   10   12   12   12    20    14    10     9
#>  [6,]   19    4   19    7    6    1   17    6    8     3     4     1     1
#>  [7,]   10   19    8    7    8   16   10    9    6     5     1    12     3
#>  [8,]   15    9    9   11    1   15   10   14   19     8     7    18    15
#>  [9,]   19    3   19    8    8   18    7    1   18    15    18     1    17
#> [10,]   19    4   20    7    6   12   12   14   15    13    14    16     7
#>       [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
#>  [1,]    15     5     8     4     5     2     1
#>  [2,]     5    12    19    11    13    18    11
#>  [3,]    10    14    15     7     8    11    13
#>  [4,]     2     4     2    11    12     6     2
#>  [5,]    15    14    13    11    10     5    14
#>  [6,]    14    16     6    12     6     2    13
#>  [7,]     5     4    15     2     1    14     9
#>  [8,]     8    10     5     2     2    14    13
#>  [9,]    19    14     1    16     7    16    15
#> [10,]    18     4    20     4    12     3    11
```

If you're not looking for sampling without replacement the fastest way should be be to fill a matrix command directly with the sampled data:

```r
matrix(sample(1:100, 200, TRUE), 10, 20)
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
#>  [1,]  100   27   99   82   15   55   27   35   77    89    16    45    10
#>  [2,]    3   96   80   87   90   51   10    4   32    40    37    29    49
#>  [3,]   99   97   30   32   34   27   56   12   62    36    57    64    25
#>  [4,]   23   29    4   60   52   71  100   26   18    19    97     9    15
#>  [5,]   77   76   63   94   27   33   68    6   42    46   100    22    43
#>  [6,]   43   84   89   90   22   90   44   59    8    71    79    14     2
#>  [7,]   97   40   39    3   91   26   26   32   33    53    75     1    65
#>  [8,]   77   91   45   36   44   92   37   22   46    73    66   100    23
#>  [9,]   44   85   42   98   80   91   32   60   42    85    52    22    11
#> [10,]    6    4   51   96   82   13   72    8    3    61    50    92    91
#>       [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
#>  [1,]    90    17    13    52    61    75    65
#>  [2,]    53    75     3    55    82    69    73
#>  [3,]    21    46    60    43    76    72    58
#>  [4,]    33    26    92    92    19    97    62
#>  [5,]    15    92    36    63    44    35    59
#>  [6,]     9    66    17    35    50    18    13
#>  [7,]    36    19    92    94    77    55    56
#>  [8,]     9    54    86    58    69    68    11
#>  [9,]    25    65    61    97    45    94    86
#> [10,]    52    42    18     4    94    49    58
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Was about to post a similar answer, with a comment about the for loop not being the best strategy. Since the question is about how to store these values in a `matrix` i think there's room to point out that the same task could be done more efficiently by something like `matrix(round(runif(200, 1, 100)), nrow = 10)`. Maybe you could add this to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, check out the `replicate` wrapper for a more concise solution that doesn't require a loop. It will give you essentially the same result, although each of the 10 random samples of 20 will run along the columns instead of along the rows (which is equivalent to the transpose of the earlier solution).

```
set.seed(100) # to make the results reproducible

x <- 10
N <- 20

replicate(x, sample(1:100, N, FALSE))
```

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   74    2   41   55   42   19   50   87   20    46
 [2,]   89   51  100   47   76   95   12   30   64    89
 [3,]   78   68   24   68   37   23   60   82   79    64
 [4,]   23   98   43   12   26   76   45   97   15    19
 [5,]   86   52    7   51   24   26   37   71  100    11
 [6,]   70   48   63   16   12    5   68   74   50    76
 [7,]    4   32   65   56    9   78   73   49   47    20
 [8,]   55   85    9   22   55   40   26    2   55    74
 [9,]   95   91   20   82   75   81   27   11   18   100
[10,]    7   39   14   53   63   97   31   47   89    82
[11,]   91   16   78    3   35   64   46    1   53    28
[12,]   93   75   88    5   58   54   71   95   84    16
[13,]   43   66    3   44   97   42   21   32   11    69
[14,]   82   70   36   85   48    3   39   73   77     7
[15,]   61   45   27   28   80   80   65   13   22    81
[16,]   12   30   46   52   98   38   16   62   52    56
[17,]   51   93   59   25   18   43   82   92   39    37
[18,]   72   29   85   42   72   83    8   58   31    72
[19,]   18   31   69   15   83    4   10   14   78    93
[20,]   25   54   47   57   66   74   69   42   76     5
```

If you want to have the 10 samples along the rows, use the `t` function:

```
set.seed(100)
t(replicate(x, sample(1:100, N, FALSE)))
```

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
 [1,]   74   89   78   23   86   70    4   55   95     7    91    93    43    82    61    12    51    72    18    25
 [2,]    2   51   68   98   52   48   32   85   91    39    16    75    66    70    45    30    93    29    31    54
 [3,]   41  100   24   43    7   63   65    9   20    14    78    88     3    36    27    46    59    85    69    47
 [4,]   55   47   68   12   51   16   56   22   82    53     3     5    44    85    28    52    25    42    15    57
 [5,]   42   76   37   26   24   12    9   55   75    63    35    58    97    48    80    98    18    72    83    66
 [6,]   19   95   23   76   26    5   78   40   81    97    64    54    42     3    80    38    43    83     4    74
 [7,]   50   12   60   45   37   68   73   26   27    31    46    71    21    39    65    16    82     8    10    69
 [8,]   87   30   82   97   71   74   49    2   11    47     1    95    32    73    13    62    92    58    14    42
 [9,]   20   64   79   15  100   50   47   55   18    89    53    84    11    77    22    52    39    31    78    76
[10,]   46   89   64   19   11   76   20   74  100    82    28    16    69     7    81    56    37    72    93     5
```